# Working out the velocity of a game object

Tags: linear-algebra

My game window is 480 width by 360 height.

My character can be anywhere on the screen (WASD controlled.)

My mouse can also be anywhere on the screen.

I can get the coordinates of the player and the mouse

How do I work out the distance between the player and the mouse?

This will need 2 functions one to work out the y difference and one to figure out the x distance

The result can be a decimal

Answer (score 1):

Subtract the two $x$ coordinates to get $dx$, the difference in $x$ and similarly for $dy$.  Then the distance is $\sqrt {dx^2+dy^2}$

Answer (score 0):

Remember that given two points $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2)$, their distance is given by
$$
\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2 + (y_2-y_1)^2}.
$$

Here is some python to help you

```
from math import sqrt
def distance(playerx, playery, mousex, mousey):
    return sqrt((playerx-mousex)**2 + (playery-mousey)**2)
```

Comment: I tried this and it works for an enemy called the tracker enemy which follows the player, but it doesn't seem to work for the shooting of bullets :( I understand that I can use Pythagoras theorem to get the distance but each object in my game has a velocityX number and a velocityY number, ie how many x to move per y every tick etc

Comment: @Robinlemon, the math works no matter what objects you use. It doesn't matter if the object has a velocity. Most likely it is your understanding of what distance is that is the problem. The formula I gave is distance, if that formula is not what you want, then what you want is not distance. If you elaborate on what you are trying to do and where it is going wrong I may be able to help you more.